# Python MySQL not all arguments converted during bytes formatting error

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have been trying the below code in Flask and getting this error: MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatting. I have checked all the post related to this in this stackoverflow and none of those worked. Would you please help with this?

---

@app.route('/update',methods=['POST','GET'])
def update():

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    id_data = request.form['id']    
    issue = request.form['issue']
    impact = request.form['impact']
    status = request.form['status']
    startt = request.form['startt']
    endt = request.form['endt']
    reason = request.form['reason']
    solution = request.form['solution']
    ticket = request.form['ticket']
    remarks = request.form['remarks']
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("""
           UPDATE incident 
           SET issue=%s, impact=%s, status=%s, startt=%s, endtt=%s, reason=%s, solution=%s, ticket=%s, remarks=%s 
           WHERE id=%s
        """,(issue,impact,status,startt,endt,reason,solution,ticket,remarks,issue,id_data))

    mysql.connection.commit()
return redirect(url_for('read'))
```

---

Comment: You have 11 elements in _(issue,impact,status,startt,endt,reason,solution,ticket,remarks,issue,id_data)_ but only 10 placeholders in your query. You need to remove the second _issue_ and set **(issue,impact,status,startt,endt,reason,solution,ticket,remarks,id_data)**

Comment: @nacho Thank you very much. I cannot believe i missed that :D